# Por que escolher C ao invés de C++ ou então C++ no lugar de C?

Tags: c, c++

Acho que todo mundo com o mínimo de conhecimento sabe quando escolher C ou C++ no lugar de outras linguagens. Existem casos claros em que estas linguagens são mais adequadas e outros que não faz tanta diferença. Mas pode haver situação em que se sabe que uma das duas seja ideal mas não se sabe qual das duas.

Quais elementos concretos devemos analisar e em que situações podemos ter certeza que o C é mais indicado que C++ ou C++ é o mais adequado?

Os motivos não precisam ser essencialmente técnicos mas eles precisam ser objetivos, precisa ser algo que os profissionais experientes nas duas linguagens costumam concordar.

Em outras palavras, quais problemas o C lida melhor e quais o C++ costuma se sair bem?

É claro que ambas podem ser usadas para qualquer projeto, mas nem sempre é a ferramenta mais adequada. Existem casos que alguns requisitos podem inviabilizar uma escolha. Que requisitos podem dificultar tanto o uso de uma linguagem que é melhor usar a outra?

Considere pontos políticos como não requisitos fundamentais, só a parte técnica importa mesmo.

Comment: Quem não entende de desenvolvimento C e C++ não sabe dizer o que faz cada uma ser mais atrativa ou não.

Comment: Excelente pergunta! estou começando meus estudos com C++ agora, vamos esclarecer essa dúvida.

Comment: Nunca parei pra pensar nisso... mas, se o que C faz, C++ faz também, então usar C++ parece ser mais vantajoso já que posso chegar o mais próximo possível de OO, o que não seria possível em C... Correto?

Comment: @sergiodeveloper não é tão simples assim. Inclusive porque OO geralmente é ruim, mas não cabe falar sobre isso aqui (é algo que poucos, verdadeiramente experientes, programadores entendem).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Responderei a pergunta apontando alguns fatos e vantagens sobre as linguagens. Faça a escolha por conta própria:

- **C pode ser compilado em qualquer arquitetura.**

Uma das primeiras coisas que acontece quando surge uma arquitetura nova é a criação de um compilador para a linguagem C (talvez tomando por base um compilador existente, apenas acrescentando um novo *target*). O ponto é que qualquer que seja a arquitetura que você encontre, é praticamente garantido que você pode escrever um programa em C e compilar nela. Isso ocorre porque C é uma linguagem "simples" e de bastante baixo nível. C++ é imensamente mais complexo e é provável que venha a encontrar arquiteturas que ainda não tenham suporte para a linguagem.

No entanto é preciso dizer que essa diferença entre as linguagens é cada vez menos significantes conforme as coleções de compiladores se tornam mais amplamente usadas. Para o GCC ou o Clang (LLVM), por exemplo, você pode adicionar novo backend que compila a representação intermediária específica dos compiladores para a sua arquitetura alvo e imediatamente terá suporte a todas as linguagens (frontend) que o compilador suporta. Se tratando de microcontroladores, o GCC suporta muitas das arquiteturas deles, sendo perfeitamente aceitável escrever um programa em C++ no lugar do usual C.

- **<strike>C é mais rápido que C++</strike>**

Mentira! Esse é um mito mais histórico que outra coisa. O fato é que compiladores de C++ são muito mais complexos que compiladores de C, logo é difícil aplicar otimizações a transformações que beneficiem a velocidade. Mas os compiladores de hoje são muito melhores que os compiladores de ontem e essa diferença está amplamente superada. A afirmativa na verdade se inverte. O C++ tem recursos que permitem escrever código mais eficiente que em C mantendo a *elegância*. Observe *templates* e funções *constexpr* como um exemplo. Mas claro, em C++ você tem muitos recursos de alto nível que seriam menos eficientes que lidar com a implementação mais simples. É claro que é menos eficiente usar `std::regex` no lugar de escrever um parser que processe um `const char*` na mão. Mas tudo que pode ser escrito em C, pode ser escrito em C++ com exatamente a mesma eficiência. Há apenas vantagens.

- **C tem uma ABI bem definida dentro de cada sistema**

Tanto o Linux quanto o Windows definem uma API em C para as aplicações usarem. Junto com isso, eles também definem uma [ABI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/187944/112052), uma forma em assembly de passar os argumentos para essas funções do sistema e de nomear-las. Sendo assim qualquer compilador vai usar o mesmo mecanismo que o sistema operacional para escrever a passagem de argumentos e a nomenclatura das funções internas do código. Isso significa que dado uma biblioteca binária qualquer, posso carregar um símbolo e chamar ele como uma função com a confiança de que estou fazendo isso certo.

Já no C++ não há uma convenção bem definida quanto a isso, cada compilador usa uma ABI diferente e não é difícil ver versões diferentes do mesmo compilador usando uma ABI diferente para acomodar algum novo recurso. Sendo assim é muito mais complicado escrever uma interface para o C++. A maioria das linguagens de script, por exemplo, só aceitam extensões nativas que tenham sido escritas em C (ou em C++, mas exportando uma interface no formado do C).

- **C é universal**

Você pode compilar C para quase qualquer arquitetura. Em qualquer ambiente você vai ter uma ABI estável. Logo, se você quer fazer uma ferramenta que gere código portável, usar C como output é perfeitamente aceitável. Observe o *bison* como um exemplo. Ainda assim, eu aconselharia a dar uma olhada no que o LLVM tem a oferecer nesse aspecto. Você gera assembly no estilo do LLVM (não é tão baixo nível quanto os assemblies para maquinas reais) e ele produz um executável na plataforma alvo. É isso que o Clang faz.

- **C++ provê recursos a custo zero**

Um lema do C++ é *zero overhead*, sobrecarga zero. Se você não usa um determinado recurso, você não paga por ele. Esse princípio garante que a linguagem seja cheia de recursos, mas, ao mesmo tempo, ela seja tão rápida quanto você queira. Basta evitar alguns pontos chaves, como RTTI (*run-time type identification*), polimorfismo ou exceções. A linguagem também pode trabalhar sem o sistema operacional, basta não utilizar a biblioteca padrão e escrever tudo por conta própria.

- **Compiladores de C são mais rápidos e gastam menos memória**

Verdade. Em geral compilar um programa em C é mais rápido por ser uma linguagem mais simples. O principal motivo para [código C++ ser mais pesado de compilar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/576452/112052) são os templates. Eles produzem grande quantidade de funções adicionais especializadas que precisam receber inline e serem otimizadas. Além dos cálculos que acontecem em tempo de compilação via expressões constantes. Quem já compilou algo que inclua *boost* que o diga. Seja como for, esse raramente é um motivo decisivo para escolher uma linguagem sobre a outra, mas um ponto a se considerar em projetos muito grandes.

- **C é o mais usado em projetos de código aberto**

Isso é mais um fator primariamente histórico. A 20 ou 30 anos, quando a maioria dos grandes projetos que vemos hoje estavam engatinhando, C++ não era tão popular e os compiladores de C++ eram muito inferiores aos de C em questões de qualidade e performance. Então ir para o C foi uma escolha natural. E hoje converter um projeto desse porte para uma linguagem diferente é uma tarefa monumental, [mas não impossível](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cxx-conversion). Com C++ é possível escrever código muito mais limpo, modularizado e organizado, as vantagens são muitas. No entanto ainda há uma grande e [irracional resistência](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/linus) ao uso de C++.

- **<strike>C é obsoleto. C++ é o substituto.</strike>**

Mais um equivoco. C e C++ são linguagens diferentes, embora compartilhem partes em comum. Cada uma possui seu uso. Mas nenhuma delas está morta. Novas revisões e atualizações são criadas regularmente, mantendo-as modernas. Como um exemplo, em 2011 ambas ganharam suporte nativo a threads. Outro ponto a deixar claro é que nem todo código de C é código válido de C++, especialmente a conversão entre tipos de ponteiros. Em C existem até mesmo recursos que ainda não chegaram ao C++, como a palavra chave `restrict`, mencionada por @luiscubal nos comentários, embora a maioria dos compiladores suporte como uma extensão.

Comment: Nunca imaginei o Linus falando uma coisa daquelas. Não sei por que mas lembrei do SOEN ao ler seu link, rsrs.

Comment: Note-se que o C pode não ser mais rápido que o C++ se escrevermos o mesmo código em ambos, mas se compararmos código C idiomático com código C++ idiomático aí já se podem notar diferenças.

Comment: Adicionalmente, o C suporta `restrict` e o C++ não. Isto tem implicações nos tipos de optimizações que podem ser feitas. Em contrapartida, o C++ tem excepções na linguagem, pelo que os compiladores podem optimizar situações de erro de uma forma que teria de ser manual (e provavelmente mais lenta) em C.

Comment: @luiscabral, me consegue um exemplo? E por favor, comparando maças com maças, recursos equivalentes.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal De quê? De idiomático, de restrict ou de excepções mais eficientes?

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Já agora, é "luiscubal", não "luiscabral". Se escrever "@luiscabral" eu não recebo a notificação.

Comment: @luiscubal Ops, autocorretor do celular. Estou curioso sobre a melhora de performance que o restrict permite (não estudei a fundo as novidades do C11). E sobre o exemplo idiomático que você pensou.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal restrict foi acrescentado no C99. Considere uma função `void f(int* A, int* B) { for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { A[i] *= B[0] } }`. Neste caso, o acesso a B é constante portanto poderia ser extraído do loop. Mas e se B = A? Ou B = A + 1? O compilador tem de ter isto em conta, pelo que esta optimização é desactivada (ou, pelo menos, é acrescentada uma verificação em runtime no inicio da função).

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Um exemplo de código idiomático C vs C++ são as strings. Em C, é idiomático usar `const char*`. Em C++, o idiomático é usar `std::string`. Se eu quiser aceder ao tamanho da string, uso `strlen` ou `size`. Mas um é de complexidade linear, o outro é constante. Ou seja, quando entramos em exemplos idiomáticos, passamos a fazer coisas diferentes (às vezes sem nos apercebermos) e as comparações acabam por deixar de ser maçãs com maçãs. É certo que o strlen do C é tão lento como o strlen do C++, mas em C++ o strlen é desaconselhado, pelo que não é justo fazer a comparação assim.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal O exemplo das strings é favorável ao C++, mas conseguiria provavelmente encontrar um exemplo favorável ao C. Mas o que interessa é a ideia geral.

Comment: O próprio Bjarne Stroutrup(criador do C++) falou que C é uma linguagem obsoleta.

Comment: Podia abordar "mito ou verdade" para "C++ tem todos os recursos de linguagem e de bibliotecas padrões que C tem, o contrário não acontece".

Answer (score 15):

**C e C++ pertencem a arquiteturas diferentes***

Apesar da possibilidade de se utilizar o paradigma estrutural C++ (c++ é multi-paradigma), porem não é possível de se utilizar o paradigma OO (em toda sua amplitude pois é possível armazenar um ponteiro para uma função dentro de um struct (fazendo um objeto meio falsificado)) em um programa escrito exclusivamente em C.

**Há uma grande quantidade de APIs dedicadas a fornecer uma interface com C++**

Há uma grande quantidade de APIs dedicadas a fornecer uma interface com C++, por experiencia própria já tive de utilizar APIs voltadas exclusivamente ao C++ (e não a C) como a do Tesseract OCR.

**C++ é bem mais poderosa que C**

C++ é bem mais poderosa que C no que diz respeito a funcionalidade devido a fato de ela ser uma extensão de C [Wikilivros](http://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programar_em_C%2B%2B/Diferen%C3%A7as_entre_C_e_C%2B%2B), o autor Robert W. Sebesta em seu livro de conceitos de linguagens de programação expõe a gama de recursos a mais que C++ possui (mesmo em paradigma estrutural).

**C é um pouco mais rápida que C++**

É possível notar uma ligeira performance extra de programas escritos em C, benchmarks comparativos podem ser encontrados em [benchmark](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u32/cpp.php).

**C e C++ estão em níveis diferentes***
Alguns autores consideram C uma linguagem mid-level enquanto C++ é considerada de auto-nível por possuir orientação a objetos, possuir recursos mais avançados e um distanciamento maior da máquina, aqui vem um observação `se C++ é um superconjunto de C então ela também pertence ao mid-level`.

Answer (score 8):

Entendo que há dois fatores principais que afetam a escolha:
1) As bibliotecas a serem utilizadas no projeto, e;
2) Domínio da linguagem;

As bibliotecas são um fator determinante. Muitos projetos utilizam bibliotecas prontas e tem de incluir módulos de declaração de classes definidas por terceiros.
Assim é mais prático que o projeto seja desenvolvido em C++. Para isolar o acesso a objetos definidos em classes haverá um esforço extra.
No caso de desenvolvimento em ambiente Windows, utilizar acesso a módulos com interface COM/ActiveX nao faz sentido utilizar ANSI C, já que o trabalho para adequar as chamadas aos requisitos desta tecnologia demandarão grandes dificuldades técnicas.

O desenvolvimento de drivers tem fatores que o tornam adequados para utilizar C. Sua características permitem por exemplo que seu código esteja contido estritamente em seu fonte, com dependências limitadas a chamadas de API de sistema.
Módulos com mínimas dependências externas tendem a ser candidatos a utilizar C como linguagem de desenvolvimento. Muitos sistemas embarcados de pequena porte usam compiladores restritos a linguagem C, forçando sua escolha.

Sentir-se confortável ao utilizar uma linguagem é um fator determinante. Portanto dominar a tecnologia afeta a escolha da linguagem. Algumas facilidades oferecidas pelo C++ são a meu ver muito atrativas em relação ao C puro.
Poder declarar variáveis em qualquer ponto do código ou garantir liberação de recursos utilizando classes são algumas.

Comment: Declarar variáveis em qualquer ponto do código é possível em C puro desde o C99...

Answer (score 5):

Minha resposta à sua pergunta seria:

**Somente use C++**

Com a seguinte ressalva: exceto se existir algum motivo pelo qual você seja *obrigado* a usar C...

Quais seriam esses motivos?

1. a falta de compilador C++ para a plataforma alvo;
2. restrições na plataforma-alvo, como problemas para implementação do tratamento de exceções; ou
3. falta de conhecimento da linguagem C++.

Há que se lembrar que **C++ é *quase* um superconjunto da linguagem C**, isto é, praticamente todos os programas ou bibliotecas escritos em C vão rodar inalterados em C++, gerando exatamente o mesmo código.

Comment: O Negrito e o "Somente" sugerem muita restrição para muitas ressalvas.

Comment: Só existe uma ressalva; os itens numerados são exemplos de motivos que se enquadram na ressalva.

Comment: Ao fazer uma afirmação tão restritiva, faz se necessário, uma argumentação mais aprofundada sobre os benefícios ou malefícios do que está sendo comparado.

Comment: -1 Dizer "somente use C++" não ajuda, nem um pouco mais do que dizer "somente use C". Principalmente porque, embora existam muitas coisas que se podem fazer em C++ que não se podem em C, existem também muitas maneiras de se introduzir _bugs_ num código usando elementos aparentemente simples de C++, como por exemplo destrutores.

Comment: Eu diria exatamente o contrário. Dê preferência ao C, que é uma linguagem menor e mais simples; só considere C++ se uma das features do C++ valer muito a pena. Isso é basicamente aplicar a regra de "menos é mais", em que a gente opta pelo mínimo necessário pra alcançar satisfatoriamente um objetivo.

Answer (score 1):

Na minha **opinião** e sendo bem direto:

C você usa quando necessita de algo mais baixo nível, algo mais próximo a linguagem de maquina. Quando você precisa usar mais os recursos da maquina de forma especifica ao seu problema, como em um projeto embarcado por exemplo.

C++ é uma linguagem de alto nível, com o maior pode de abstração. Com ela é possivel a utilização de orientação à Objetos, a qual facilidade o desenvolvimento de sistema. Muitas vezes, sistemas comuns do dia a dia

Espero ter ajudado ;)