# Qual a diferença entre c e c++

Tags: c, c++

Estou iniciando na programação e gostaria de saber a diferença entre `c` e `c++` e qual devo começar para facilitar os estudos.

Comment: Se não for duplicada, então é baseada em opinião, porque você quer um conselho pessoal.

Comment: C não tem classe :P hehe.

Answer (score 4):

Você está fazendo duas perguntas aqui. Basicamente as suas perguntas são:

- Qual é a diferença entre C e C++?
- Por qual (dentre C e C++) começar os estudos?

Acerca da primeira pergunta, são duas linguagens de programação diferentes, mas é importante se frisar que C++ consiste da linguagem C com um monte de aditivos feitos por outras pessoas. É bem difícil de se encontrar um programa C que não seja válido em C++, mas é fácil de se encontrar um programa em C++ que não seja válido em C.

Note que isso não significa que o C seja algo obsoleto que pode ser substituído pelo C++. Veja mais sobre isso [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19073/132).

Por fim, sobre a sua segunda pergunta, isso é totalmente opinativo (o que não é bom de acordo com o formato deste site). Há quem vai te dizer que é melhor começar pelo C e há quem vai te dizer que é melhor começar pelo C++. Mas, lembre-se que como quase todos os programas válidos em C também são válidos em C++, e visto que ambas as linguagens são supercomplexas, então por este lado valeria a pena começar pelo C. Por outro lado, alguém poderá afirmar que com isso você não aprenderá programação orientada a objetos logo no princípio, e que portanto C++ seria melhor. Há também mais um monte de motivos para argumentar para ambos os lados.

Answer (score 1):

Ambas são linguagens de programação e usadas normalmente para criar jogos bem como sistemas comuns, diferenças:

C é uma linguagem estrutural

C++ é uma linguagem orientada a objetos

Eu recomendaria começar por C, já que é mais fácil e simples para quem está começando com a programação.

Bons estudos!