# Onde está o erro? "system is not declared in this scope''

Tags: c++

É suposto fazer isto https://gyazo.com/ae18e6b29f3ffc73c02f518a73145cc4
Eu elaborei isto https://gyazo.com/3729ab0e204f3dc49fff3ec9773155eb

Mas na parte do maior de 15 anos ele não me deixa escrever para ler o nome...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");
    int idade;
    char nome;
    printf("Introduza a sua idade\n");
    scanf("%d",&idade);
    switch(idade){
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9:
        case 10:
        case 11:
        case 12:
        case 13:
        case 14:
        case 15:printf("Lamentamos mas ainda não tem idade para executar este programa");break;
        default:printf("PARABÉNS Pode prosseguir");
        system("color 8A");
        printf("Digite o seu nome e apelido");
        scanf("%c",&nome);
        printf(" %c você tem %i anos",nome,idade);break;

    }
}
```

Erro diz: "system is not declared in this scope"

Comment: Explique o problema também, não da pra entender muito bem o que tem de errado no código e nem o que você espera dele pelo texto da pergunta.

Comment: na última parte ele não me pede para digitar o nome e apelido

Comment: Sim não entendo muito bem mas acho que procedi corretamente nesse código no entanto o último scanf não está a funcionar no programa afetando também o printf asseguir....

Comment: Entenda primeiro o que é IDE e compilador http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/3635 e depois entenda o que é C e o que é C++ http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19073/3635

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para usar o `system` adicione o [stdlib.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/)

Troquei o `switch` pois estava desnecessário.

Troque `scanf("%c", &nome);` por `scanf("%s", nome);`, note que troquei `%c` por `%s` e remove o `&` na variável nome, pois a referencia é desnecessária.

Veja se é isto o que deseja:

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* printf */
#include <stdlib.h> /* system */
#include <locale.h> /* setlocale */

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");

    int idade;
    char nome[80]; //limitei o char para 80

    printf("Introduza a sua idade\n");
    scanf("%d", &idade); //int requer referencia

    if (idade > 15) {
        system("color 8A");
        printf("PARABÉNS Pode prosseguir\n");
        printf("Digite o seu nome e apelido\n");

        scanf("%s", nome);
        printf("%s você tem %i anos\n", nome, idade);
    } else {
        printf("Lamentamos mas ainda não tem idade para executar este programa\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

No caso usei `if` e `else`:

```
if (idade > 15) {
```

Os `switch` podem ser usados melhor de outra maneira, recomendo que procure estudar o básico de `if`, `while`, `for`, `switch` para entender o que esta fazendo

**Recomendo que leia:**

- [Por que escolher C ao invés de C++ ou então C++ no lugar de C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19073/3635)
- [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/3635)

Comment: Está a dar erro. Retirei o break mas mesmo assim diz ''system is not declared in this scope''

Comment: o compilador? Eu uso o dev c++ e gravo em c source

Comment: hmm, continua com o mesmo erro que apresentava no meu inicial de switch, não me pede para digitar o nome.

Comment: Está sempre com o mesmo problema... :/

Comment: Deixa estar, a ajuda já me ajudou a entender melhor o que estava a fazer errado, agora é só corrigir essa parte da saida. Depois falo com a minha stora e ela ajuda-me no resto :)

Comment: Nessa parte continua a fazer o código de igual maneira ao compilar em c++ e em c source diz que nao tem a biblioteca que acrescentas-te

Comment: https://gyazo.com/ad9debf52f6e6157b16036cca9d1c0d2

Comment: @NopeNope não entendi, pela sua print do ecrã (tela) parece ter entrado no `if`. Ou é o `scanf` que não está funcionando?

Comment: é o scanf que não dá :7

Comment: Não consigo dar run porque nao tem essa biblioteca

Comment: @NopeNope atualizei o código e coloquei algumas explicações

Comment: Já percebi :), afinal até o programa que eu tinha feito em switch estava bem, o problema era a saida estar em char e não em string. Já agora sabes de alguma publicação aqui ou noutro site que explique os básicos de while,for,if e else? Também estou com várias dificuldades nessa parte por não perceber o seu correto funcionamente e a forma como as váriaveis são identificadas.