# O que significa compatibilidade binária?

Tags: .net, terminologia, arquitetura-computadores, software

Eu li sobre esse termo e não consegui chegar em uma definição exata. Seria a compatibilidade de uma biblioteca/DLL com a versão da IDE utilizada? Falo isso em relação ao ambiente do .NET Framework, mas acredito que esse conceito seja bem mais extenso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não tem um contexto maior, pode ser até que alguém usou a expressão em algum lugar onde não devia.

Pra mim, compatibilidade binária está relacionado com a integração direta de binários em uma mesma aplicação, rodando sob o mesmo processo. Precisa ter a mesma [ABI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/187944/101) e outros pontos que cada parte consiga se comunicar perfeitamente sem precisar de uma tradução de como comunicar ou uma intermediação não binária.

Não consigo ver o que IDE tem a ver com isso, [são coisas distintas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101). E de maneira geral você pode trabalhar com um IDE qualquer com binários quaisquer.

Pode haver alguma utilidade do IDE que mexe nos binários e isso pode não funcionar se ele não souber mexer em uma determinada versão, mas é algo pontual.

Parte da questão é se dá para colocar tudo no mesmo *container*. Por exemplo não dá para colocar um código gerado em C (dentro do que se faz normalmente) junto com um código gerado pelo C# no mesmo arquivo (`.DLL`). Mas dá para fazer ambos conversarem no mesmo processo. Tem alguma compatibilidade binária, mas não total. Embora isso andou mudando um pouco, não sei como está, mas o [AOT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/568799/101) pode ter mudado isso e ter a compatibilidade total agora (pelo menos deveria já que o executável final com AOT é gerado pela infraestrutura do C++.

Em alguns contextos a compatibilidade binária está se referindo ao conjunto de instruções que ele executa, ou seja, se é para x86, x64, ARM, um [IL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138577/101), etc.

Eventualmente pode estar falando da compatibilidade com a plataforma onde roda, ou seja, se é Linux, Android, Windows, *browser*, etc.

É a característica de dois objetos executáveis poderem rodar juntos, diferente de ter que recompilar o fonte para tornar compatível.