# Se C/C++ são linguagens nativas então por que precisam de runtimes?

Tags: c, c++, runtime

Geralmente a primeira coisa que vinha a minha mente quando ouvia o termo linguagem nativa, era um programa que executasse independente de sistema operacional, se comunicando direto com o hardware, eu sempre desenvolvi em modo *debug*, quando soltei uma *release* pela primeira vez notei que compiladores até como MinGW precisavam de uma *runtime*, se fosse uma aplicação que utilizasse Windows API por exemplo seria totalmente compreensível pois depende de bibliotecas do sistema operacional Windows. Mas se há a necessidade de uma *runtime* então por que chamar de linguagem nativa?

Imagino um *hobista* desenvolvendo um computador bem simples (algo como um chip-8) então ele começa a desenvolver seu kernel para o sistema operacional, em algum momento ele vai ter que deixar de lado o Assembly e usar C/C++, então como o programa vai lidar com algo de tão baixo nível sem uma *runtime*?

Comment: Se usar o MinGW-w64, por exemplo, (que é um fork moderno) não precisa do runtime (mingwm10.dll, por exemplo). Não confundir com  a biblioteca de exceções, a biblioteca de threads e nem a stdlib, cada uma tem sua função (independente do runtime) - Sua pergunta está misturando muitas coisas não relacionadas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Geralmente a primeira coisa que vinha a minha mente quando ouvia o termo linguagem nativa, era um programa que executasse independente de sistema operacional, se comunicando direto com o hardware

Errado, uma linguagem nativa depende do sistema operacional. Pelo menos não há a exigência que não precise de um sistema operacional, e se não tiver um, então o *runtime* passa ser fundamental, afinal a linguagem sozinha (o código gerado por ela) só pode dar instruções para o processador. O acesso direto ao hardware é possível, mas não é simples.

> eu sempre desenvolvi em modo *debug*, quando soltei um *release* pela primeira vez notei que compiladores até como MinGW precisavam de uma *runtime*, se fosse uma aplicação que utilizasse Windows API por exemplo seria totalmente compreensível pois depende de bibliotecas do sistema operacional Windows.

Acho que falta entendimento do que é um *runtime*. Ele é código necessário para executar certas tarefas de uma forma mais fácil e segura.

Você não precisa de um *runtime* em Assembly, em C também, ou quase. De certa forma em C++. Só que na prática dará trabalho, você terá que fazer tudo na mão e provavelmente está reinventando a roda de uma forma pior. Raramente estará se livrando do código necessário para funcionar corretamente, apenas está fazendo na mão.

Bibliotecas contam como *runtime* ou não? Na prática sem elas não dá para fazer nada útil, a não ser as reescrevendo. O que talvez esteja chamando de *runtime* são as bibliotecas. Não é errado dizer isso, mas é possível deixar isso de fora. Você terá pouca vantagem em relação ao Assembly, provavelmente apenas portabilidade de arquitetura.

O *runtime* tem mecanismos para facilitar sua vida, se você os usar. Ou para resolver um problema da implementação ou da plataforma, não da linguagem.

> Mas se há a necessidade de um *runtime* então por que chamar de linguagem nativa?

Já que isso é uma premissa equivocada você deveria fornecer um motivo porque uma linguagem nativa não poderia ter um *runtime*.

Linguagem nativa significa que o código roda diretamente no processador, só isso, que não tem um processo intermediário de interpretação.

Na verdade o termo já está errado. Não existe linguagem nativa, existe implementação nativa. Podemos dizer que toda linguagem pode ser nativa ou não. Algumas tendem mais ser uma coisa ou outra, mas, salvo algo na especificação que exija exclusivamente um desses sentidos, e nem C, nem C++ tem esta exigência, você pode fazer uma implementação não nativa.

> Imagino um *hobista* desenvolvendo um computador bem simples (Algo como um chip-8) então ele começa a desenvolver seu *kernel* para o sistema operacional, em algum momento ele vai ter que deixar de lado o Assembly e usar C/C++

Não, ele pode continuar usando Assembly.

> então como o programa vai lidar com algo de tão baixo nível sem um *runtime*?

Não sei como essa pergunta faz sentido, muito menos qual a dúvida aqui. Se entendi certo essa pergunta invalida os pressupostos originais da questão.

## Conclusão

Acho que está confundindo termos e conceitos. Não há relação entre essas coisas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Acho que estou confundindo os termos de Runtime mesmo, por exemplo quando lancei uma release de um programa que usa Qt, além das dll's do Qt precisei de algumas dlls que não tinha no kit do Qt MSVC (Eu estava usando a versão MinGW): libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll, libstdc++-6.dll e creio que libwinpthread-1.dll coisa que não tinha na versão do MSVC (Por que deve estar no pacote redistribuíveis do Visual C++, esse realmente é uma runtime segundo a página de downloads)

Comment: "Não, ele pode continuar usando Assembly" - Quando eu falei que algum momento ele deve recorrer a C/C++ é devido ao fato que a pouca experiencia que tive com asm pude ver que é uma linguagem complexa, demorada de se criar aplicações para uma tarefa simples como mostrar um "Hello World", e como você mesmo disse https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19073/por-que-escolher-c-ao-inv%C3%A9s-de-c-ou-ent%C3%A3o-c-no-lugar-de-c C pode ser compilado para qualquer arquitetura, o que iria agilizar o desenvolvimento.

Comment: Fazer um hardware ou sistema operacional é bem mais complexo. Eu acho mais simples fazer um "hello world" em Assembly que em em outra linguagem, mesmo sem conhecer bem a linguagem. Se é para o seu hardware essa portabilidade parece pouco importante.